# Is being shameless the same as being confident

Tags: meaning, synonyms

Could you say that one who is acting "shamelessly" or "brazenly" is acting "confidently"?

The Oxford Dictionary doesn't list "confidently" as a synonym for either, but I've found the word to be interchangeable with both.

Comment: "Shameless" means you're either too brazen to feel shame or too stupid to know you should.

Answer (score 2):

Shameless means without shame.  Confident means with security.  While confidence does indicate lack of shame, they are not equivalent.

One can be shameless and yet lack in confidence.

Brazenly indicates with little regard to danger / consequence.

Comment: While you are correct, your answer could be better by including sources (OED, Cambridge, Merriam-Webster etc) and copying the relevant information (e.g. definitions).

Comment: I wouldn't say that confidence indicates a lack of shame.  Someone might confidently confess to a shameful past, or exhibit confidence in spite of something shameful in his past.  And it takes either confidence or a degree of foolhardiness to intentionally behave in a manner that others would regard as shameful.

Comment: @HotLicks either way, one can be an element of the other, but in neither case are they equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

[Confidence](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/confidence), according to the basic Oxford definition, is:

> The feeling or belief that one can have faith in or rely on someone or something:

It is often used about a person having confidence in himself/herself, which is  [self-confidence](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/self-confidence)

> A feeling of trust in one’s abilities, qualities, and judgement:

It could be used, for example,  to describe a person making a speech in public. A confident public speaker does not seem embarrassed, shy or awkward.  The opposite of a confident person is someone who is shy, obviously self-conscious, or may appear not to know what he is talking about. At a party a confident person will be mixing easily with everybody, whereas a less confident person may stay in the kitchen, rather hoping nobody speaks to him. A person who is very lacking in confidence would probably not have gone to the party in the first place.

[Shameless](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/shameless) is defined as

> Of a person or their conduct) characterized by or showing a lack of shame; barefaced or brazen:

Shameless is used to refer to a person who is doing something immoral, or which the speaker regards as immoral, but either doesn't seem to realise it, or doesn't care.

A scenario may help illustrate the difference.

Let's suppose Andy has some biscuits on his desk and his colleagues would like one. Confident Clare will go up to Andy and ask him if she can please have one of his biscuits. Awkward Angela will go almost up to his desk and then end up saying nothing, or make some remark about the weather. She lacks the confidence to ask and so she never gets a biscuit. Shameless Sarah will go straight up to Andy, even while he is sitting there, and simply help herself to a biscuit. She either doesn't think it wrong to take other people's biscuits, or if she does, she doesn't care. Thieving Thelma will wait until Andy has gone to the bathroom and then help herself to a biscuit when nobody is looking.

Clare and Angela are both honest, but Clare has confidence and Angela doesn't.

Sarah and Thelma are both dishonest, but Sarah is shameless and Thelma is not.

Comment: Wonderful explanation.

Comment: +1, but you forgot Brazen Barbara, who walks up, takes the last three biscuits, and asks Andy to cover for her while she takes a long lunch.